# What does the "Be optimistic on external API" option do?

Tags: .net, code-contracts

In the "Static Checking" options for Code Contracts there is an option named **"Be optimistic on external API"**. I cannot find any documentation on what this option does.  How does it affect the analyzer's behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does indeed not seem to be any documentation about this option.  Browsing the source gives a few clues.  In [`Options.cs`](https://github.com/Microsoft/CodeContracts/blob/master/Microsoft.Research/ClousotMain/Options.cs) this links to a boolean `lowScoreForExternal`:

```
[OptionDescription("Be optimistic on external API? 
                    We will assign proof obligations depending on that a low score")]
[DoNotHashInCache]
public bool lowScoreForExternal = true;
```

Where in the [`WarningScoresManager`](https://github.com/Microsoft/CodeContracts/blob/master/Microsoft.Research/Analyzers/WarningScoresManager.cs) this is used during initialization to set the score assigned for extra info in an external assembly.  With the option turned on, the same score is applied if referencing a different assembly as is applied for a framework assembly, otherwise a very high penalty applies.

```
private void InitializeDefaultValuesForContextsOfCalleeAssumeCanDischarge
  (bool lowScoreForExternalAPI)
{
   // ...
ScoreCalleeAssumeExtraInfoDeclaredInAFrameworkAssembly = .05;
ScoreCalleeAssumeExtraInfoDeclaredInADifferentAssembly = lowScoreForExternalAPI ?
        ScoreCalleeAssumeExtraInfoDeclaredInAFrameworkAssembly : 100.0;
```

It would seem that using this setting forces the analyzer to assume a similar level of trust about the code quality of external assemblies as is afforded to framework assemblies.

This seems to be the only use of this variable - it is passed to the `WarningScoresManager` in the constructor and is not used anywhere else.